# Using IF operator with Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to assign numbers to a certain types of building and I need to use field calculator. I tried many different versions of this and I still can't find what's wrong.  Could you tell me where do I make a mistake?

[image: ![Printscreen]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E91tb.png)

Comment: obyv column is a short type... I tried float (among others) but didnt help.

Comment: Looks like a script for **VB** instead of Python, perhaps check the parser for VB Script?

Comment: Artwork 21 has answered this but just for your info (and sanity) write your field calculator expressions in a text editor that supports python syntax highlighting. Notepad++ or similar. It will greatly decrease frustration - the field calculator is such an unfriendly tool.

Comment: Yep, I just found out how unfriendly it is. I will use notepad next time. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your python syntax is not correct, try:

```
def myFunc(typ, oby):
  if typ == 'D':
    return 'Z'
  else: return '25'
```

function call:

```
myFunc(!TYP!, !obyy!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working if/then statement in VBS.

For your code, I would think something like this:

```
Dim result
if [TYP] = "D" then
     result = "Z"
else result = "25"
end if
```

And:

```
obyv = result
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used "=" rather than "==".

```
def countRows(rowcount): 
    import arcpy 
    if %rowcount% == 0: 
        return "false" 
    else: 
        return "true"
```

Comment: There is no need to `import arcpy` and I think doing so would make this run very slowly.